# If $f$ is continuous on $A,$ is it true that $\{x:\text{osc}_f(x)=0\}=A?$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I am reading [Kechris's Classical Descriptive Set Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387943749).
Kechris prove the following theorem at page $16.$

> *Theorem* $3.8$ (Kuratowski) Let $X$ be metrizable, $Y$ be completely metrizable, $A\subseteq X,$ and  $f:A\to Y$ be a continuous function.
>   Then there exist a $G_\delta$ set $G$ with $A\subseteq G\subseteq \overline{A}$ and a continuous extension $g:G\to Y$ of $f.$

The following is a definition of $G_\delta.$

> Let 
>   $$G = \overline{A}\cap\{x:\text{osc}_f(x)=0\}.$$
>   This is a $G_\delta$ set and since $f$ is continuous $A,$ $A\subseteq G\subseteq \overline{A}.$

Then the proof proceeds with the standard construction of $g$ on $G.$ (Essentially, for any $x\in\overline{A},$ get a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x.$ Then the sequence $(f(x_n))_n$ is Cauchy and thus has a limit in $Y.$ Define $g(x)$ to be the limit.)

The following is my question.

> *Question*: Is $G=A?$ Since $f$ is continuous on $A,$ so $\{x:\text{osc}_f(x)=0\} = A.$ Am I right?

Comment: No. $\mathrm{osc}_f(x)$ is  defined for all points $x \in \overline A$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I can try to point you in the right direction. How do you (or does Kechris) define the oscillation.

Comment: Based on the book, $\text{osc}_f(x) = \inf\{ \sup\{d(f(x),f(y)):x,y\in U\}: U\text{ an open neighbourhood of }x \}$ where $f:A\to Y, A\subseteq X, X$ is a topological space and $(Y,d)$ is a metric space.

Comment: That definition isn't quite right. That might be the source of confusion.

Comment: @Umberto P. May I know what is your definition of oscillation?

Comment: You overloaded the symbol $x$. For $\mathrm{osc}_f(x)$ to be defined you don't need $f(x)$ to be defined; rather every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ must contain a point $y$ where $f(y)$ is defined. If $A$ is the domain of $f$, this requires $x \in \overline A$.